# XML data to HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

I have the following function that is displaying info from an xml file:

```
<?php
function adddata(){
$dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
$file = $dir.'visits.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$data = $xml->xpath('/VISITORS/VISIT');
foreach($data as $visit){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->EMAIL.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->PHONE.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->IPADDRESS.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->HOSTNAME.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->BROWSER.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->CURRENTPAGE.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->REFERER.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->GPS.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->ISP.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->CITY.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->STATE.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->COUNTRY.'</td>';
echo '<td>'. $visit->TIME.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';               
}
}
?>
```

And this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <VISITORS>
        <VISIT>
            <IPADDRESS>173.16.185.54</IPADDRESS>
            <EMAIL></EMAIL>
            <PHONE>515-123-1234</PHONE>
            <CURRENTPAGE>http://www.example.com/example.php</CURRENTPAGE>
            <REFERER>http://www.google.com</REFERER>
            <HOSTNAME>173-16-185-54.client.mchsi.com</HOSTNAME>
            <BROWSER>Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36</BROWSER>
            <ISP>AS30036 Mediacom Communications Corp</ISP>
            <GPS>37.2999,-93.3084</GPS>
            <CITY>Springfield</CITY>
            <STATE>Missouri</STATE>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
            <TIME>Thursday, June 30, 2016 16:14:43</TIME>
        </VISIT>
        <VISIT>
            <IPADDRESS>173.16.185.54</IPADDRESS>
            <EMAIL>example@example.com</EMAIL>
            <PHONE>515-123-1234</PHONE>
            <CURRENTPAGE>http://www.example.com/example2.php</CURRENTPAGE>
            <REFERER>https://facebook.com/</REFERER>
            <HOSTNAME>173-16-185-54.client.mchsi.com</HOSTNAME>
            <BROWSER>Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36</BROWSER>
            <ISP>AS30036 Mediacom Communications Corp</ISP>
            <GPS>37.2999,-93.3084</GPS>
            <CITY>Springfield</CITY>
            <STATE>Missouri</STATE>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
            <TIME>Thursday, June 30, 2016 16:17:33</TIME>
        </VISIT>
        <VISIT>
            <IPADDRESS>202.46.13.63</IPADDRESS>
            <EMAIL></EMAIL>
           <PHONE></PHONE>
            <CURRENTPAGE>http://www.example.com/example4.php</CURRENTPAGE>
            <REFERER></REFERER>
            <HOSTNAME>msnbot-202-46-13-63.search.msn.com</HOSTNAME>
            <BROWSER>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)</BROWSER>
            <ISP>AS8075 Microsoft Corporation</ISP>
            <GPS>41.8500,-87.6500</GPS>
            <CITY>Chicago</CITY>
            <STATE>Illinois</STATE>
            <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
            <TIME>Thursday, June 30, 2016 16:17:36</TIME>
        </VISIT>
        <VISIT>
            ... More Visits ...
        </VISIT>
        <VISIT>
            ... More Visits ...
        </VISIT>
    </VISITORS>
```

Notice the first two "visits" are from the same ip address but only the second one contains an email address, because the first time they visited the site, the information wasn't available.

If they are from the same ip address, how can I display the correct email for that visitor on all table rows that contain that ip address?  (I don't need to change the xml file, just output the data, but I am not opposed to changing the xml file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create an array in which you save the email to the ip, if the email is not empty and the ip is not already set as index in the array.

Then just use the ip as index to display the corresponding email.

Though this way, for every ip there can not be different emails. You could however implement another check if the current email is different from the saved one. You could also simply replace the email in the array every time the email is not empty, depends on how you want to handle those cases.

```
function adddata() {
    $file = 'test.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $data = $xml->xpath('/VISITORS/VISIT');

    $ipToMailArray = array();
    foreach ($data as $visit) {
        if(!array_key_exists((string)$visit->IPADDRESS, $ipToMailArray) && (string)$visit->EMAIL !== ''){
            $ipToMailArray[(string)$visit->IPADDRESS] = (string)$visit->EMAIL;
        }
    }
    foreach ($data as $visit) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . (($ipToMailArray[(string)$visit->IPADDRESS] !== '') ? $ipToMailArray[(string)$visit->IPADDRESS] : '') . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->PHONE . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->IPADDRESS . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->HOSTNAME . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->BROWSER . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->CURRENTPAGE . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->REFERER . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->GPS . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->ISP . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->CITY . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->STATE . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->COUNTRY . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $visit->TIME . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Though, while you are in the first loop you could also simply fill the array with all the data. Then just return the array so the function doesn't have to handle your html output. (Or maybe just rename your function so it is communicated cleary this function is supposed to output something)

Comment: Oh thanks. Yeah so he would have to iterate over the data before outputting them, not a big problem.

Comment: @Philipp - I tried the above code before and after your edit, and both now output email address as empty....  (but so you know, the entered email will always come after the empty emails in the xml file)

Comment: oh damn sorry, gotta cast the SimpleXMLElement to string. edited. Also added something to check if the email really isn't in the xml, so there won't be a notice

Answer (score 1):

In case of empty email, you can query the node with the same `IPADDRESS` and not empty `EMAIL` like this:

```
function adddata($file)
{
    $dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
    $file = $dir . 'visits.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $data = $xml->xpath('/VISITORS/VISIT');
    foreach($data as $visit) {

        if(empty($visit->EMAIL)) {
            //Select the node with the same IP and filled email
            $node = $xml->xpath("/VISITORS/VISIT[IPADDRESS/text() = '{$visit->IPADDRESS}' and EMAIL/text()]");
            if($node && count($node)) {
                $visit->EMAIL = $node[0]->EMAIL;
            }
        }

        echo "-> ".$visit->EMAIL. "<br>";
    }
}
```